# Change Custom Toolbar Text

Tags: android, textview, android-toolbar

Unable to get the text on my toolbar to change. I have done a tone of searching but I am seeing no results.

I have tried so many combinations of things but maybe something will pop out.
Here is the code for the last thing I have tried for my activity.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarCustom);
TextView textView = (TextView)   toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTextView);
textView.setText("String");
```

Here is my XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_item_action"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.carson.tryeverything.ItemActionActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"

   >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarCustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Line one"
          android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


 <FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        />

  </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
        android:visibility="visible" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Lastly here is my Manifest File. Probably needs a little cleaning

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="no spoilers" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ItemActionActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"/>
</application>
```

I have three activities, the Splash, the main screen which has 2 dozen listview options and then the final activity screen where I want the toolbar to show a custom title depending on which you click on.

Comment: Are you using supportActionBar()?

Comment: Please post all the code that involves Toolbar.

Comment: We need the code of your third activity (the one that has toolbar) too.

Comment: Sorry thought it was extra unnecessary information, added my third activity which my toolbar coded is included into, I have tried various code involving supportActionBar as well and have had no results. Though if there is a specific code you want me to try let me know and I'll let you know what happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot to set this:

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

---

**YOUR ACTIVITY LIKE THIS:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarCustom);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

TextView textView = (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTextView);
textView.setText("String");

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need!

Answer (score 9):

It will be like that. Java Code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //here toolbar is your id in xml
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("String"); //string is custom name you want
```

Answer (score 1):

I never get it, Why anyone doesn't simply write all toolbar custom text inside the xml? why bother writing code in .java file?
e.g.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_custom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_22ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Profile"/>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Often in my projects, the title is dependent on the data passed in to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you change custom toolbar text in Android Kotlin:

First go to the Manifest file and i your activity add the line android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" in your activity tag

```
<activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
 </activity>
```

Second go your Activity and add the following:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.title = "My New Title"
}
```