# Marquee toolbar title not working when using proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, android-toolbar

I'm trying to marquee title in toolbar, but the marquee is not working if I build it with proguard enable.

```
    Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
    f.setAccessible(true);

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);
    titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    titleTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    titleTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Seem like "mTitleTextView" is obfuscated by proguard.

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mTitleTextView
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
```

But it doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct proguard **not** to touch private fields with following syntax:

```
    -keepclassmembers class android.widget.Toolbar {
        private android.widget.TextView mTitleTextView;   
    }
```

For the toolbar from support library:

```
    -keepclassmembers class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar {
        private android.widget.TextView mTitleTextView;
     }
```

<sup>See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field) question for more details.</sup>

Comment: Helpful: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing reflection. Private field names can change at any time, not to mention that using reflection is slow! Also, from Android 9 Pie (API 28), [they're locking down API access](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) so it's not a long-term solution.

Instead, define your own Toolbar in a layout instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43643720/818821) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936714/818821).